# Do word contractions and brief sentences make for a more conversational speech?

Tags: grammar, style, conversation

I'm currently studying what makes a sentence sound/ read conversational to native English speakers. Do word contractions and brief sentences make them so?
Please consider the dialogues below. Are both dialogues conversational enough?

**Dialogue 1:**
I don't like the idea of having a government-funded news network. It has a tendency to be partial and cover-up political scandals.

**Dialogue 2:**
Imagine a father sitting as judge in a criminal case against his own son. Sure, he could say that he'd be fair. But the people wouldn't buy that and would still ask him to inhibit from the case. That's because he has a strong tendency to decide in favor of his son.

Comment: What do you mean by "conversational enough"? How much is enough?

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  Both dialogues sound fine and are easy to read.

Comment: Hi Ray! Welcome to ELL. Your first paragraph is a good question. We can't help you with advice about the dialogues underneath, though. We don't do proofreading on this site (we'd get overwhelmed). Would you like to edit those bits out? (I can do it for you, if you'd like.)

Comment: @Ray, please note that a dialogue is a conversation between two or more people. The passages above are not dialogues, as each passage sounds like it was spoken by one person. Do you mean that you want to write in a style that would be appropriate for a dialogue, like a movie script?